# How to effectively show no network in webview

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an Android webview application and how can i effectively show no network page with a button to retry the current page agian.. i have googled a lot and not yet find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

use a swipe refresh or a button on toolbar which on every refreshing call this line:

```
webView.loadUrl(url)
```

for handling the state of WebView, you can implement an inner class extended from "WebViewClient" like this :

inner class WebClientCustom : WebViewClient(){

```
override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)

}

override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url)

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?, error: WebResourceError?) {

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, errorCode: Int, description: String, failingUrl: String) {
}
```

}

here you can handle your errors in onReceivedError function, and customize your view according to parameter `error: WebResourceError`.

Comment: I had did this but i dont want to show the inbuilt network error connection page for webview. So i can i achive this with a custom network error webpage with a retry button in it

Comment: Thanks for your reply i have created my own network connectivity class to check whether  the network is available over wifi,mobile data and i have only made a reload request only if the network is available. By doing this its working efficiently now **Thanks for your feedback**

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this behaviour, you can add a web view client that listens for errors in loading a given url. In there, you can find a callback that will be called if something goes wrong and if you check for  **ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP** or **ERROR_UNKNOWN** then you can assume that the connection is not right and display the error.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // set the action for the retry button
    retryButton.setOnClickListener {
        // hide the error view and show the web view
        retryView.visibility = View.GONE
        webView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        loadUrl(). // reload the url
    }

    webView.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
        override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?, error: WebResourceError?) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
            if (error?.errorCode == ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP || error?.errorCode == ERROR_UNKNOWN) {
                displayErrorView()
            }
        }
    }
    loadUrl()

}

// load the url
private fun loadUrl() {
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com")
}

// display the error view
private fun displayErrorView() {
    retryView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    webView.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

I think that if you use this, then you will be able to display a custom error. However, there are two problems that have to be fix:

1. If no internet connection is present and you tap very fast on the retry button, the UI will keep flickering between error view and web view. Not a huge issue, but it happened before on Android with ProgressBar if they were shown and hidden very fast. You can check the `ContentLoadingProgressBar` to see how it was fixed and replicate the same behaviour.
2. After a connection is established, the web view will still show the default error message while reloading the url. Maybe you can display also a custom loading view that will be hidden when the page is finished loading. See the `onPageFinished` from the web view client.